# Finding where I need to update the naming Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I renamed my project, and updated it to .Net 5. Now, I obviously havent catched all the occurances since I get this error:

```
\source\repos\BlazorBattles\BlazorBattles\Server\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages\Error.cshtml.g.cs(78,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'blazor_battles' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\hagenek\source\repos\BlazorBattles\BlazorBattles\Server\BlazorBattles.Server.csproj]
```

However, it is hard to locate it, because the error shows a file that is being generated by the project ,not a file that is in the core project.

Any tips?

Comment: dotnet clean, dotnet build

Answer (score 1):

For some reason visual studio could not locate the string "blazor_battles" in the Error.cshtml file inside of Server/Pages directory.

Using hyphens in your project names creates problems. Don't do it.